# StreamingPathFilter trims spaces

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xom

I use the [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/) library to parse and process .docx documents. MS Word stores text content in runs (<w:r>) inside the paragraph tags (<w:p>), and often breaks the text into several runs. Sometimes every word and every space between them is in a separate run. When I load a run containing only a space, the parser removes that space and handles it as an empty tag, as a result, the output contains the text without spaces. How could I force the parser to keep all the spaces? I would prefer keeping this parser, but if there is no solution, could you recommend an alternative one?

This is how I call the parser:

```
StreamingPathFilter filter = new StreamingPathFilter("/w:document/w:body/*:*", prefixes);
Builder builder = new Builder(filter.createNodeFactory(null, contentTransform));
builder.build(documentFile);
...

StreamingTransform contentTransform = new StreamingTransform() {

   @Override
   public Nodes transform(nu.xom.Element node){
      <...process XML and output text...>
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found the solution to this issue, thanks to the hint of *Elliotte Rusty Harold* on the XOM mailing list.

First, the `StreamingPathFilter` is in fact not part of the `nu.xom` package, it belongs to `nux.xom`.

Second, the issue was caused by `StreamingPathFilter`. When I changed the code to use the default `Builder` constructor, the missing spaces appeared in the output.

Just for documentation, the new code looks like the following:

```
Builder builder = new Builder();
nu.xom.Document doc = builder.build(documentFile);
context = XPathContext.makeNamespaceContext(doc.getRootElement());
Nodes nodes = doc.getRootElement().query("w:body/*", context);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
    transform((nu.xom.Element) nodes.get(i));
}
...

private void transform(nu.xom.Element node){
    //process nodes
    ...
}
```